# How can I bind ComboBox ItemSource in a DataTemplate to a List?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I am very new to WPF, C#, XAML, etc.  But I am learning.  So far I am having trouble binding a ComboBox ItemSource in a DataTemplate to a C# string List.

Here is my C# code:

```
public class Giraffe {
    ...
    public Zebra() {
        AnimalStuff.Add("Head");
        AnimalStuff.Add("Stripes");
        AnimalStuff.Add("Tail");
    }

    private List<string> _animalStuff= new List<string>();
    public List<string> AnimalStuff {
        get { return _animalStuff; }
        set {
            _animalStuff= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AnimalStuff");
        }
    }

    #region OnPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is my XAML code:

```
...
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="AnimalTemplates.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
...
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalStuff}" />
```

That part works perfectly.  I get a combobox with a dropdown list of all of the AnimalStuff strings.

However, I need to put that combobox in a DataTemplate.  I can't get the binding to work.  Here is the DataTemplate file:

```
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="AnimalTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="GridAnimalTemplate" >
        ...
        <Label Content="Select Animal Part:" />

        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalStuff}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I add this to the XAML file:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource AnimalTemplate}" />
```

In the ListBox, I get the proper label and the combobox to appear.  But the combobox is just empty since it can't find the AnimalStuff list to bind to.  I've tried setting the binding RelativeSource to various settings but I can't seem to ever get it to find the list in the C# code.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the `ItemsSource` of your ListBox?

Comment: I do not have one.  When I tried adding it I get this message:Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Comment: that means you manually added some item for your ListBox, so what are they?

Comment: I had this code in there to make the ListBox show up in the code: <listbox name>.Items.Add(new Object());  Removing that allows it to run.  But how do I create an ItemsSource for a ListBox with multiple controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

King King got me going on the right track.

Here is the correct answer: In the C# code you need to create a new list.

```
List<AnimalListboxItem>[ AnimalItems = new List<AnimalListboxItem>();
public class AnimalListboxItem{
    public string AnimalPartLabel { get; set; }
    public List<string> AnimalStuff{ get; set; }
}
```

Then use that new list as the item source for the listbox:

```
AnimalItems = new List<AnimalListboxItem>();
<listbox name>.Items.Add(new AnimalListboxItem
    AnimalPartLabelBound = "Select Animal Part:",
    AnimalStuffBound = AnimalStuff);
```

Then you can do the binding in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AnimalTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="GridAnimalTemplate" >
    ...
        <Label Content="{Binding AnimalPartLabelBound}" />

        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalStuffBound}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can put as many things as you want in the AnimalListboxItem class including arrays, other lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Add Interface of `INotifyPropertyChanged` for first, and lets see what happens after.

If not working please chechk the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186985/wpf-binding-to-parent-itemscontrol-from-inside-of-child-itemscontrol-data-templa) also

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you're adding items to the List versus when you're setting the list as the `ItemsSource`, the `ComboBox` may not reflect updates to the `ItemsSource`. Use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  See my accepted answer.  But thank you for your time.