# Filter out some items from ComboBox in XAML/WPF only when an external flag is set

Tags: wpf, xaml

The idea is almost the same as in [How to hide items of a combobox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099669/how-to-hide-items-of-a-combobox-in-wpf).

In my `ComboBox`, I am showing multiple items, and I need to be able to hide irrelevant/incompatible items from the `ComboBox` when an external flag is set (in my case it is a boolean `Checkbox` with name `ShowAllItems`).

My `ComboBox` is bound to a list of items of a type which is "aware" of their compatibility status (a field named `IsSupported`). I just need to hide/show these items depending on whether the `Checkbox` is ticked or not.

A naïve approach would probably be adding/removing items from the list each time a `Checkbox`'s status is changed.
Another (also probably naïve approach) would be to add a new field to the items of the list `IsVisible`, and then update this field each time a `Checkbox`'s status is changed.

To summarize, my filter would depend on an item's `IsSupported` field and on the `Checkbox`'s `ShowAllItems` field.

The `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSupported}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

and the `Checkbox`:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowAllItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Show all items"/>
```

Comment: use `MultiDataTrigger`

Comment: But how can I bind the boolean property of the Checkbox "ShowAllItems" to the DataTrigger of the Combobox? They live in different scopes? I would need something like Binding="{Binding PARENT.ShowAllItems}"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186985/wpf-binding-to-parent-itemscontrol-from-inside-of-child-itemscontrol-data-templa. use RelativeSource: `{RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}` (and note DataContext in binding path)

Comment: It works, perfect! Would also be interested in reason behind why both `AncestorType=ComboBox` and `AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}` work. It seems ambiguous but it still works fine.

Comment: very simple reason: ComboBox class inherits ItemsControl, so both types can be used in this situation

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSupported}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowAllItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Thanks to @ASh for pointing out that I need to use `MultiDataTrigger`, and how to bind the `Checkbox`'s `ShowAllItems` property (which lives in a different scope).

Also note that `IsEnabled` setter needs to be used to prevent user from selecting the item through usage of keyboard arrows up/down as well as mouse scroll wheel.