# WPF - How to change ContentControl view from sub-view?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, delegates

I'm new to WPF/MVVM and building an application which runs "Jobs".
The aplication currently looks like this:
[image]

The `MainView` contains some buttons and a `ContentControl`. The `ContentControl` shows some sub-views like `JobsView` or `ApplicationSettingsView`, depending on the selected menu item.

The `JobsView` contains blocks which represents a job. It shows some job information, job functions and an edit button (Bewerk) to edit/configure the job.

When i click on the button "Bewerk", a job specific edit view should be shown in the `ContentControl` of the `MainView`. I'm looking for the best way to handle this navigation. Important is that i have the instance of the concerning job available in the `JobEditViewModel`.

**I tried:**

1. Passing a function to the `JobsViewModel` (https://linuxhint.com/passing-function-as-parameter-c-sharp/) when its created in the `MainViewModel`. This does not work as the `JobsViewModel` is called twice somehow (noticed during debugging). One time from the `MainViewModel` and one time from ???. The second time, it calls the constructor without params so i cannot call the passed function. After some research i also read that its bad practice to pass params to `ViewModel` constructors.

```
...
namespace ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    internal class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private object _currentView;
        private Engine engine;

        public JobsViewModel JobsVm { get; set; }
        public SettingsViewModel SettingsVm { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand JobViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand SettingsViewCommand { get; set; }


        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                engine = Engine.Instance;
            });

            JobsVm = new JobsViewModel((viewModel) => { this._currentView = viewModel; });
            SettingsVm = new SettingsViewModel();

            _currentView = JobsVm;

            // Initialize relay commands
            JobViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { CurrentView = JobsVm; });
            SettingsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { CurrentView = SettingsVm; });
        }
    }
}
```

```
...
namespace ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class JobsViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<RJob> _jobs;

        public ObservableCollection<RJob> Jobs { get => _jobs; set { _jobs = value; } }

        public RelayCommand ForceRunJobOnceCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand StartJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand StopJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand EnableJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand DisableJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand EditJobCmd { get; set; }

        public string btnEnableDisableContent { get => "test"; }

        public JobsViewModel() {

        }

        public JobsViewModel(Action<BaseViewModel> changeContentView)
        {
            _jobs = Engine.Instance.RJobs;

            ForceRunJobOnceCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).ForceRunOnce(); });
            StartJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Start(); });
            StopJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Stop(); });
            EnableJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Enable(); });
            DisableJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Disable(); });
            EditJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { changeContentView(new VerzamelqueryViewModel()); });
        }
    }
}
```

2. Using Events and Delegates. (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event) This does also not work. The event handler in `MainView` is not called/triggered for some reason. It also feels not nice to go for this solution as i have no idea how i can register an event handler when the sub-view is not created/initiated from the `MainView` but from another sub-view. (e.g. the `EditJobView` will get a sub-sub view to show logs of the concerning `Job` and include a back button to go back to the `EditJobView`) Its also feels not realy generic/reusable. (need to implement a new event and event handler for each sub-view that handles navigation)

```
...
namespace ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    internal class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private object _currentView;
        private Engine engine;

        public JobsViewModel JobsVm { get; set; }
        public SettingsViewModel SettingsVm { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand JobViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand SettingsViewCommand { get; set; }


        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                engine = Engine.Instance;
            });

            //JobsVm = new JobsViewModel((viewModel) => { });
            JobsVm = new JobsViewModel();
            JobsVm.ChangeView += (object sender, BaseViewModel newView) => { _currentView = newView; };
            SettingsVm = new SettingsViewModel();

            _currentView = JobsVm;

            // Initialize relay commands
            JobViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { CurrentView = JobsVm; });
            SettingsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { CurrentView = SettingsVm; });
        }
    }
}
```

```
...
namespace ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class JobsViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<RJob> _jobs;

        public ObservableCollection<RJob> Jobs { get => _jobs; set { _jobs = value; } }

        public RelayCommand ForceRunJobOnceCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand StartJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand StopJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand EnableJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand DisableJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand EditJobCmd { get; set; }

        public string btnEnableDisableContent { get => "test"; }

        public event EventHandler<BaseViewModel> ChangeView;

        public JobsViewModel()
        {
            _jobs = Engine.Instance.RJobs;

            ForceRunJobOnceCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).ForceRunOnce(); });
            StartJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Start(); });
            StopJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Stop(); });
            EnableJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Enable(); });
            DisableJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ((RJob)o).Disable(); });
            EditJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { ChangeView?.Invoke(this, new VerzamelqueryViewModel()); }); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Whats the best practice/WPF-MVVM way to handle my case?**

------- Udate:
Views in case they are needed ...

MainView:

```
<Window x:Class="ECRO.MVVM.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ECRO.MVVM.View"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="880" Width="1000"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Border
        Background="#272537"
        CornerRadius="20">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Border Height="35"
                       Width="1000"
                       Margin="0"
                    CornerRadius="20 20 0 0"
                       Background="#22202f">
                <DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel Width="930" 
                               Background="Transparent"
                               PreviewMouseDown="drawWindow">
                        <TextBlock Text="ECRO - ECB Robot" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Margin="0 5 10 0">
                        <Button Content="—"
                            Width="20" Height="20"
                            Margin="5 5 5 5"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontSize="15"
                            Click="minimizeApplication"/>
                        <Button Content="X"
                            Width="20" Height="20"
                            Margin="5 5 5 5"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontSize="15"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DockPanel>

            </Border>

            <Grid Height="845" Width="1000">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="ECB Robot"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Foreground="White"
                       FontSize="22"
                       Margin="20 0 0 0"/>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" 
                        Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <RadioButton Content="Jobs"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"
                             IsChecked="True"
                             Command="{Binding JobViewCommand}"
                             />
                    <RadioButton Content="Settings"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"
                             Command="{Binding SettingsViewCommand}"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Stop robot"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBox Width="250" 
                     Height="40"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Margin="5"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Style="{StaticResource Textbox}"/>

                <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="10"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>

            </Grid>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

JobsView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ECRO.MVVM.View.JobsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:widget="clr-namespace:ECRO.MVVM.Widgets"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" Height="780">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:JobsViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Jobs" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}"/>
        <ScrollViewer Width="780" Height="700">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Jobs}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:JobWidgetViewModel}">
                        <widget:JobWidget/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

JobWidget:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ECRO.MVVM.Widgets.JobWidget"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="110" d:DesignWidth="760">
    
    <!--<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:JobWidgetViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>-->

    <Grid>
        <Grid Height="110" Width="760">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="677*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="123*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border CornerRadius="10"
                    Background="#353340"
                    Height="100"
                    Margin="10,0,10,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="50*"/>-->
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Margin="5 2 0 0">
                        <Label Content="Naam" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="Status" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="Laatste run" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="Volgende run" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="Schema" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Status}"  Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding LastRun}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding NextRun}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Schedule.Type }" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                    </StackPanel>


                    <Border Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Margin="0 0 20 0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="Forceer run" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Width="100"
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.ForceRunJobOnceCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="Start" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.StartJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="Stop" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.StopJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button x:Name="btnEnable"
                                        Content="Enable"
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.EnableJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button x:Name="btnDisable"
                                        Content="Disable"
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.DisableJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="Bewerk" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding Main.EditJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an event aggregator or a messenger to raise events or pass messages from one view model to another. The concept is explained in [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/).

The idea is that the `JobsViewModel` raises a "navigation" event that the `MainViewModel` handles without introducing a direct dependency between the view models.

Another option is to inject `JobsViewModel` with an `INavigate` or `INavigationService` interface that is implemented to switch the view, for example by doing what the `MainViewModel` currently does.

A third option is to bind directly to a command of the `MainViewModel` from the `JobsView` using a `{RelativeSource}`:

```
<Button Content="..." Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SwitchViewCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, realy usefull answer, i got it working with the third option as it does not require any aditional code. Though i like the Event aggregator thing, i was looking for this but couldn't find it. I defenitely will use this on another place(s) in the project.

Answer (score 0):

> When i click on the button "Bewerk", a job specific edit view should be shown in the ContentControl of the MainView. I'm looking for the best way to handle this navigation.

this requirement means that MainViewModel is responsible for navigation, not JobsViewModel. so EditJobCmd command should be in MainViewModel, and not in JobsViewModel (and it eliminates the necessity to pass a delegate via constructor)

Comment: Ok, i agree that the `MainViewModel` is responsible for the navigation but the button is inside the `JobsView` so how to notify the `MainViewModel` that it needs to change the view? Thats the whole question...

Comment: button inside item template can bind to a higher level DataContext: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186985/wpf-binding-to-parent-itemscontrol-from-inside-of-child-itemscontrol-data-templa/57818488#57818488

Comment: and if it is not an inplace DataTemplate, but some UserControl, then that UserControl control can define a dependency property for edit command

Comment: How do you mean a `dependency property for the edit command` Something like: `  Command="{Binding DataContext.StartJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"` as i do this for my other buttons. I added my `XAML` files so you can see what i mean.